# Laravel Cart Sum based on input from 2 different tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 tables Bag(cart) and products. I am saving quantity added by user in bad table and sale_price in products table. I need to get sum of bag.quantity * products.sale_price for each item. I am using query builder to get sum. How can i get that

I am able to use join to get list of all attributes

```
$items = DB::table('bag')->where('bag.user_id' , $user_id)->where('bag.order_id', 0)->join('products','products.id','=','bag.product_id')->get();
```

api link:

```
https://apptest.factory2homes.com/api/get-bag-products/3
```

I need to multiply quantity and sale_price for each unique product_id and then take total sum of it

Comment: What you want to get?

Comment: I need to multiply quantity and sale_price for each unique product_id and then take total sum of it. I have edited question with api link as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) to do such thing:

```
$items = DB::table('bag')->where('bag.user_id' , $user_id)
            ->where('bag.order_id', 0)
            ->join('products','products.id','=','bag.product_id')
            ->selectRaw('*, (bag.quantity * products.sale_price) as totalPrice')
            ->get();
```

and to get sum of all, you can use [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sum):

```
$sum=$items->sum('totalPrice');
```

Comment: how can i take sum of all totalPrice?. this is giving totalPrice for each row saved in bag table.

Comment: i have updated my answer to get sum of all total prices